# Nodemailer with E-Mail Templating working locally but not in AWS Lambda environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, nodemailer, email-templates

I am developing a small webapp that has user accounts. So I want to send E-Mails regarding their registration and E-Mail Address Confirmation.

I am using the Serverless Framework with Express and Node.js as well as Nodemailer with email-templates.

here is the mailer.js function to send a confirmation email:

```
function sendConfirmation (name, address) {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.strato.de',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.STRATO_USER,
            pass: process.env.STRATO_PASSWORD,
        }
    });

    const email = new Email({
        transport: transporter,
        send: true,
        preview: false,
    });

    console.log("Sending Email");

    email.send({
        template: 'confirmation',
        message: {
            from: 'company',
            to: address,
        },
        locals: {
            fname: name,

        }
    }).then(() => console.log('email has been sent!'));

}

module.exports = {
    sendRegister,
    sendConfirmation
};
```

And here is the code of the route. I look for the user in the database and update him to be confirmed. Then I try to send the email.

```
router.post("/confirmation", async (req, res) => {
  userId = req.body.userId;
  let userUpdated = false;
  let updatedUser;
  updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {"confirmed": true}, function (err, result) {
    if(err){
      res.send(err)
    }
    else{
      userUpdated = true;
    }
  });

  if (userUpdated) {
    await sendConfirmation(updatedUser.name, updatedUser.email);
    res.json({error: null, data: "User confirmed"});
  }

});
```

If I test this with `app.listen` on localhost I receive the E-Mail without any problems. As soon as I deploy it to AWS with Serverless, the user gets updated in the DB, but the E-Mail is not send. It seems that Lambda does not wait until the promise of the  `email.send()` is there? I also tried to explicitly allow the Lambda function to communicate with port 465 on outbound traffic. No luck.

In the logs of the Lambda function no error is shown, but also no confirmation of the sent email.

Has anyone an idea what I am missing? Thank you very much!

**EDIT 1:**

I just found out, that if I use `await sleep(2000)` with an according function

```
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

right after calling the `sendConfirmation` function and it works without problems. It seems, that the sendConfirmation function will not wait for the promise of email.send. Any idea how to solve this? I am fairly new to promises.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using SES to send the email message?

Comment: Hi, no I'm using SMTP to connect to our mail provider. Could that be a problem? That lamdba is not able to connnect externally?

Comment: This could be an issue -- https://serverfault.com/questions/955461/connecting-to-smtp-server-from-aws-lambda

Comment: I found out, that If i use `await sleep(2000)` with an according function like `function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}` it works withput problems.